OpenAI API throws Bad Request when uploading a file
I am using the Python version of the OpenAI API and trying to upload a file with the following code:
client.files.create(file=myFile, purpose="fine-tune")
The client has been initialized with a valid API key, and other calls to the API (to send text prompts) work correctly, but when I try to post a file I get a "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" error.
I have verified that the file exists and is a readable text file (the code logs the first line of the file before posting it).
The code used to initialize myFile is:
myFile = open(file_path, "rb");
What could the problem be?

What kind of file are you trying to upload?

@codeananda A text file containing a table with columns separated by tabs, like this:
Column A Column B Column C Column D Column E Column F Column G     Column H       Column I  Column J content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content  content
Only with line breaks, which I cannot add here for some reason.

If has to be a .jsonl file. Doesn't look like yours is. What happens if you do client.files.create(file=open(file_path, "rb"), purpose="fine-tune")? If that still doesn't work, please add some code to your question that I can copy/paste.

Thank you, @codeananda! When this project started, the API did not have that restriction and we were able to upload text files in the above format. Thank you for letting me know of this change! I can upload the file now.

As stated by @codenanda, I was using the wrong file format. The current version of the OpenAI API only supports JSON files.
